# Как объединить(склеить) несколько видео в один видеофайл?

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите как используя Python, можно склеить несколько avi-шных файлов в один видео файл?

Comment: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: @НикитаФаст, если я правильно понял, то для соединения видео файлов, нужны операции конката? Так?

Answer (score 1):

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
clip1 = VideoFileClip("myvideo.mp4")
clip2 = VideoFileClip("myvideo2.mp4").subclip(50,60)
clip3 = VideoFileClip("myvideo3.mp4")
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2,clip3])
final_clip.write_videofile("my_concatenation.mp4")
```

https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/compositing.html